# AWS amplify console.log() from backend side

Tags: aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I have set up a serverless express function (integrated with API gateway) using "amplify add api".
If I log something from one of the routes for example:

`app.get('/items', function (req, res) {console.log('hello')}`

Where do I find the hello?

Comment: Is this code in a Lambda function or on a web application?

Comment: This is a Lambda function which runs when I make a Get request to an endpoint generated by amplify.

Comment: You can check it under `Cloudwatch Logs`.

Comment: Nice it works now. However if I make a change locally in VS code to the lambda function. I need to use "amplify push" to update the function in the cloud. So I guess my question is: is there a way you can view changes locally?

Comment: You mean view the logs locally from your terminal in real time?

Comment: Yes exactly from my terminal.

Comment: Same here. Even in Cloudwatch I cannot see it (any console.log inside API handler function. I'm using nextjs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can view the `console.log()` using AWS CloudWatch Logs.

But as you want to view the logs from your terminal I would recommend using [awslogs](https://github.com/jorgebastida/awslogs).

Comment: How exactly can I see the console.log? I see only the incoming requests and responses. And nothing about my app output.

Answer (score 0):

They are logged to CloudWatch, but they might be in a different region from your application (try Oregon).